# How to add case insensitive to photo gallery search box jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

folks I am "newbie". I have small assignment. I have to create a search box for "Photo Gallery". I did it by using "data-keywords" in HTML list items also I made it to respond to lower and upper case, but the problem is that I want to be case insensitive, but can't figure out how to do it. There are some suggestions with ":contains" selector other with RegEx, but either I can't implement those suggestions or I totally mess up the code. Here is the code https://jsfiddle.net/Lnvaagd3/ Thank you in advance :)!

```
$("#search").keyup(function() {

    var currentQuery = $("#search").val();

    if (currentQuery !== "") {

        $("#list li").fadeOut(100);

        $("#list li").each(function() {

            var currentKeyword = $(this).attr("data-keywords");

            if (currentKeyword.toLowerCase().indexOf(currentQuery) >= 0) {

                $(this).fadeIn(200);

            } else if (currentKeyword.toUpperCase().indexOf(currentQuery) >= 0) {

                $(this).fadeIn(200);
            }

        });

    } else {

        $("#list li").fadeIn(200);

    }

});
```

Comment: What about converting both to lower or uppercase for comparison, instead of looking at each separately? Something like: `if(currentKeyword.toLowerCase().indexOf(currentQuery.toLowerCase()) >= 0)`

Comment: Thank you mark.hch ! Ror the rsponse. This is working as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
var currentQuery = $("#search").val().toLowerCase();
// ----------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

And using that you will not need the `else if`.

This way both the `currentQuery` and `currentKeyword` will be in lowerCase letters, in other words, this line:

```
if (currentKeyword.toLowerCase().indexOf(currentQuery) >= 0) {
```

will act as case insensitive.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Washington Guades. You're the man ! Thank you so much you saved me so much time!

Comment: @ViktorYakov. Glad to help :)